# Why ssh -nq -t can't see my environment variable?

Tags: ssh, scripting, environment-variables, remote

I am executing a command on remote machine with -t flag ( to prevent the command from 'blocking' ) the prompt (somehow it works that way). So I am using `ssh -nq -t root@ip` but with this, the script cannot find my environment variable that I use.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid this ?

Comment: Where is the environment variable defined?

Comment: In .bashrc file .

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409951/can-i-forward-env-variables-over-ssh ?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

The information below is valid if you `ssh` into the machine and then run your command which starts a login shell:

```
ssh root@ip
echo $XXXX_LICENSE_FILE
```

If you are trying to access the variable directly from the `ssh` command (`ssh root@ip echo $XXXX_LICENSE_FILE`) then you are starting a **non-login, non-interactive** shell in which case neither `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bashrc` are read. From the `bash` man page:

```
   When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script,
   for  example,  it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the envi‐
   ronment, expands its value if it appears there, and  uses  the
   expanded  value  as  the  name  of a file to read and execute.
   Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
          if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
   but the value of the PATH variable is not used to  search  for
   the file name.
```

The easiest workaround would be to simply declare the variable along with the `ssh` command. For this to work, you need to add this line to the remote `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

Then run this from the local machine:

```
XXXX_LICENSE_FILE=/etc/xxxx.lic && ssh -nq -t -t -t root@$ip /etc/init.d/xxxx.rc start
```

---

The problem here is the difference between login and interactive shells. See [here](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile) for a nice summary.

`~/.bashrc` is only read when starting an **interactive** (non-login) shell. When you `ssh`into a remote machine, you are running a **login** shell so `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` (in that order) are read instead. You can check this by running `bash` after loging on to the remote server, that will start an interactive shell, `~/.bashrc` will be read and your environment variable will be set.

To fix this, define the variable in your `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

---

I am assuming that you are setting the variable in the remote `.bashrc`, not your local one. If you want to export a *local* variable over `ssh`, have a look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410137/1081936) posted by Frederik Deweerdt. The easiest way would be to include your variable in the invocation of `ssh`:

```
ssh -nq -t root@ip "FOO=foo BAR=bar"
```

Comment: Even after defining the variable in `.bash_profile` system can't find the variable.

Comment: @Patryk please explain exactly what you are doing. How is the variable defined and where (local `.bash_profile`, or remote?) and how are you trying to access its contents. Is the remote shell bash?

Comment: I have the variable both in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` defined as follows `export XXXX_LICENSE_FILE=/etc/xxxx.lic`, then I have in script `ssh -nq -t -t -t root@$ip /etc/init.d/xxxx.rc start`

Comment: OK. You mean the _remote_ `/root/.bash_profile` right? Are you sure the remote shell is bash?

Comment: Yes, I am `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`. And yes - the remote one.

Comment: @Patryk see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support but I still cannot solve my problem. With `XXXX_LICENSE_FILE=/etc/xxxx.lic &&  ssh -nq -t -t -t root@$ip /etc/init.d/xxxx.rc start` run from local machine I still get the error that `Can't find environment variable "XXXX_LICENSE_FILE"`. If I run this `/etc/init.d/xxxx.rc start` manually it goes without a problem though.